# Curl does not work when passes in variable from file

Tags: bash

I am not sure why using the variable inited from a file does not work. 
I wrote a function to CURL a list of domains from a file (only one line at this time, www.google.com). But the CURL returns empty when the $domain is read from the file. When I echo $localvar, it always displays the correct value (www.google.com in this case).
I hardcoded "www.google.com" for a test, the CURL did return the page as expected.

What did I miss? Thanks in advance!

Bash version 3.2.57(1)-release

```
#!/bin/bash

function processDomains() {
    local inputfilepath=$1;

    while read domain
    do      
        local localvar="$domain"     
        #localvar="www.google.com" --- uncomment this line the curl command works
        #echo $localvar --- always display domain correctly
        local result=$(curl -sL "$localvar");

        echo "$domain" "$result"  
    done < $inputfilepath
}
```

Comment: Any chance you've got the file from Windows with CRLF line endings?  Maybe Bash is keeping the CR in `$domain`.  You could use `echo "[[$domain]]"` in the loop to see whether the close brackets are misplaced in the output, a sure sign of CR problems.  Surrounding what you echo with other known printing characters (I used `[[` and `]]`, but the choice is wide open) can help a lot.

Comment: Please post the contents of your input file.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You are right. I changed the file ending to LF which solved the issue. Thank you very much !!

Answer (score 1):

Jonathan's comment answered my question. It was caused by the CRLF ending from the file.